# How to index 32-character text id

Tags: postgresql

I have 32 character long text IDs from another system that I want to store and be able to query fast.  Here is an example: `rl3j6cUkVf06W6fZCqmqn6o3RzeCh186`

What type of index would be best suited?  I am reading about full text indexing, but is that really what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for a full text index, but for a normal index. That is, you are looking for the key.

You can either choose to have it as primary key:

```
create table a (
    id char(32) not null primary key
)
```

Or have a custom primary key and use this key in a unique index

```
create table a (
    id bigserial primary key,
    external_id char(32) not null unique
)
```

Both of them will optimize for queries like `select * from a where id = $1`.

In case these values are not unique, you need to explicitely create the index:

```
create table a (
    id bigserial primary key,
    external_id char(32) not null
);
create index on a (external_id);
```

Comment: Thanks.  These ids are actually `category_id` mapping to an external service.  For example, I have a products table with primary key id and other attributes, but I need to add this `category_id` column since it maps to the service we are using.  The `category_id `can be repeated.  In that case, is a regular index still the way to go?  Thanks

Comment: hey @user1354934 I've added an example with that case you mentioned. Yes, indeed. If you are looking for key then a regular index (btree underneath) is what you need. Other kinds of indexes are for other operations, like partial searches, similarity searches...

Comment: As a side note: `char(32)` offers no performance or storage advantages over `varchar(32)` But if it can happen that the id gets shorter then 32 characters `char(32)` will was space.